# objective c removing all future events from calender using ekevent store

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, icalendar, ekeventstore

i am using this method to delete some specific event in an iphone app, using EKEventStore

[eventstore removeEvent:event span:EKSpanFutureEvents commit:YES error:&err];

but now my requirement is changed, now i have to delete all created event from current date, for example if today is 2nd july 2013, then i have to delete all future created events from 2nd july 2013. i am trying to do it like this,

```
-(void)deleteAllEvents{

    EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:self];
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *startDate = [today cc_dateByMovingToBeginningOfDay];
    NSDate *endDate = [today cc_dateByMovingToEndOfDay];
    event.startDate = startDate;
    event.endDate = endDate;
    [event setCalendar:self.defaultCalender];

    NSError *err;
    [self removeEvent:event span:EKSpanFutureEvents commit:YES error:&err];



    if(err)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",[err localizedDescription]);
    }


}
```

but i am not getting the desired result. plz. guide me about this thanx and regards Saad.

i am working in xcode 4.5 with ios sdk 6.1.

Comment: I have same issue have you got any solution for the same
Thanks

Comment: I got solution using event identifier. Try this

    EKEventStore* store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init] ;
    EKEvent* eventToRemove = [store eventWithIdentifier:strIdentifier];
    if (eventToRemove != nil) {
        NSError* error = nil;
        [store removeEvent:eventToRemove span:EKSpanFutureEvents error:&error];
    }